# Linked list for firestore documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a use case to make a linked list of documents like 
{ name, next_ptr} and next_ptr is a reference to another document

I have following code and I am getting next_ptr but not getting fields belonging to  next_ptr

**I am getting following output**

```
KkkGTTKjuwcGmzJzQ3Wa => FIRE => undefined

iW9lm7sYkgvuZPdVvrZE => GAS => undefined

NtTyJNjqIT79PZ6zkqtY => WATER => undefined
```

**Expected Output**

```
KkkGTTKjuwcGmzJzQ3Wa => FIRE => GAS

iW9lm7sYkgvuZPdVvrZE => GAS => WATER

NtTyJNjqIT79PZ6zkqtY => WATER => undefined
```

**Code**

```
db = defaultApp.firestore() ;


abc_collection = db.collection("abc") ;

abc_collection.get() 
.then( data => {
  data.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.id , "=>", item.get('name')) ;

next_ref = item.get('next_ptr') ;
    next_ref.get("name").then(item => {
      console.log(item) ;
    }).catch("") ;

  } ) ;
}).catch("") ;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't really know what next_ptr is in your database, how you populated it, or even if it's populated correctly.  Screenshots might be helpful to illustrate what you've got, or maybe even code that created the documents.

Comment: next_ptr is a reference to another document

Comment: Your code suggests it's not defined.  Since we can't see your data, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: screenshot added

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're assuming that the query results contain all the referenced documents:

```
item.get('next_ptr')['name']
```

What `item.get('next_ptr')` returns is a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object, not the entire contents of the document.  You will have to query that document with its [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method in order to load its contents, or find the document using its ID in the results that you queried (if you guarantee that the reference always points to a document in the same collection.

You might just be better off storing the string ID of the document if you don't want to deal with the DocumentReference.

Comment: Since next_ptr can be from different collections I want to put reference. I will try .get method on next_ptr. In another I will post an exact use case to check if I have a design issue

Comment: (node:8652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: next_ref.get is not a function

Comment: You're going to have to check the case where next_prt is not a reference.  It looks like you've chosen to use an empty string in some cases.

Comment: My approach is wrong for this linkedlist problem, I should get a single document and then use next_ptr. I will change my code retry.